# Remove comma from comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to remove comma from string value of comma separated values.

I am parsing mysql insert queries for my project, and i am failing when string value contains comma.

I am working in php.

Example :

```
$temp = "INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1,'name','some random, address')";
```

as in above example, i want to remove the comma between `some random` and `address`.

Actually queries contains too many fields and complex values.

### UPDATE

I hadn't mentioned my problem in depth, regrets.

I am reading from a mysql dump file, fetching insert queries in one array, then parsing each query.

## SOLUTION

```
preg_replace("/,(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/", '', $var_name);
```

will do the work, Thanks @Avinash Raj & @MarkusQ

Comment: That means you're not actually *parsing* it. See [SQL parser in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8970499)

Comment: Are you sure that the comma is the problem? The string has an issue with mis-matched quotes: `'some random, address"`

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, BeatAlex  sorry, had typos.

Comment: @ErrHunter did you want to remove the commas which are present within single quotes?

Comment: It is always good to use Prepared statements rather than direct sql queris. Youc an check this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I am not using mysql, i am just parsing mysql queries.

Comment: @ErrHunter how about this http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/23 ?

Comment: What's the problem with commas?

Comment: @ErrHunter: If you're working with a file, will you consider non-PHP solutions also like Unix shell scripts etc?

Comment: @anubhava it must be in php, client requirement.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I want to remove commas, coz in later processing i will explode the string using commas, so if comma is in string value then that will fail.

Comment: ok in that case duplicate linked answer might help.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Solved thanks ! I did google before posting but my keywords for search was different. Post as your answer,i will accept.

Comment: @ErrHunter it's a duplicate question , so i marked it as duplicate.. Posting answer for a marked duplicate question is not quite right. You're always Welcome :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj :) Appreciated !

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can use

```
 $string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
```

But in the example given, you are missing a closing **'** before **"** and the query won't execute.

Comment: Then my all commas will be replaced, i jut want to remove comma between  'some random' and 'text' if referring example string.

Comment: $string = str_replace('random,', 'random', $string);

Comment: But even better, you can use Prepared Statements to prevent this.

Comment: please at least consider my regex, it does actually match only the comma you want to replace. maybe a new export would be better, but sometimes a regex does the job too.

Answer (score -2):

If you have problems in your sql and there is no way of exporting again you could use a regular expression to improve the replacing.

```
$regex = '/(,)(?!\'.*\))/';
```

I suggest something like preg_replace($regex, '', "INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(1,'name','some random, address')");

Comment: ahh not so stupid my regex :-)

Comment: +1 for trying regex, but your regex doesnt work.

Comment: then try (,)(?!\'.*\)), shit stackoverflow removes some of the regex

Comment: here is a online tool to create and test http://www.regexr.com/. There are many of those out there and hey; regex always help :-)

Comment: Thnks bud for help !

Comment: What I would do is convert the comma-separated string into an array and use array_walk function to remove the comma in every elements. Finally, convert back the modified array into an string